# How to loop through multiple custom post types?

Tags: wordpress

I'm unable to get this wordpress loop to work: I'm trying to get it to display two post types, the slugs are 'movie' and 'tvshow'.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here - It's displaying whichever post type I put first after the =>, and they both work by themselves.

```
<?php 
$movieArg = array('post_type' => 'movie', 'tvshow');
$query = new WP_Query($movieArg);
while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
?>


<div class="movie">

<h2><?php the_title(); ?> </h2>

</div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Friend, while statement should contain while {}.

Comment: @abdulla Sorry, could you give me an example of the proper way to implement?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue with the way you're specifying multiple post types.

They need to be listed inside an array. Right now you're setting the post type to `movie` while `tvshow` is another element in the main array.

Change this:

```
$movieArg = array('post_type' => 'movie', 'tvshow');
```

To:

```
$movieArg = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'movie', 'tvshow', ), 
);
```

Comment: Ah, ok. That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!